# Mathematical expectation of variable X

Tags: statistics

X is random variable (see the image)

[image: X]

Can E[X] get more simplified

Thank you Vladimir, I was on the similar trace:

[image]

Comment: Where is your own effort?

Comment: I'll also try to solve it, if I do I'll post it

Answer (score 1):

Hint
$$
\frac{kb^k}{(1+a)^{k+1}}=\frac b{1+a}\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\frac{b^{k}}{(1+a)^{k}}.
$$

1. Sum the geometric progression.
2. Differentiate, multiply by $b/(1+a)$.
3. Set $b=a$.